# Explain finding the max of a forward list using recursion c++

Tags: c++

So my professor created this code and I don’t fully understand it so I would like an explanation if possible of what exactly is going on. I specifically don’t understand the difference of temp_item and max_item in the second piece of code... Much appreciated

```
T SLL:: max()
{
    if (empty()) 
        throw std::range.error(“”);
    auto temp_item=*begin();
    return max(begin(),temp_item);
}

T SLL:max(iterator i, T&max_item) 
{
    if (i==end()) 
        return max_item;
    if (max_item > max(next(i), temp_item)) 
        return max_item;
    else
        return max(next(i), max_item);
}
```

Comment: `temp_item` is not defined inside of `max(iterator, T&)`. Also, `max(iterator, T&)` should not be called twice inside of itself like this code is doing. That iterates the list redundantly, causing a performance penalty. Call it once and save the result, then return the result if needed. `T SLL:max(iterator i, const T &max_item) { if (i==end()) return max_item; T temp_item = max(next(i), max_item); if (max_item > temp_item) return max_item; return temp_item; }`

Comment: `return *std::max_element(begin(), end());`